# Image upload via Ajax in PHP[simplest way]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have studied a lot of answers in stackOverflow but haven't figured out the simplest way of uploading an image from a form. I am trying to figure out a way to upload an image using Ajax. Although the form,  PHP and Ajax coding is huge, I am giving you the important parts. When I click the submit button, error message is shown, viz `undefined index`.

`HTML`

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <td><input type="file" name="image" id="img"></td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

`Ajax`

```
$(document).on('click','#sub_prod',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"product_add_back.php",
            method:"post",
            data:$('form').serialize(),
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(strMsg){
                    $("#prod_add").html(strMsg).show().fadeOut(3000);

                }

            })

})
```

`PHP`

```
$image_name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
echo $image_name;
die();
```

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47364397/2815635)

Comment: `serialize` does not includes files. Check this: [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: @C2486 I have data in my form, tried using the answer you suggested but it stops the form fields from getting submitted.

Comment: @Justinas, thanks, trying your way. `formData`, would really appreciate if you could give out a solution in the answers.

Comment: you can add form field in loop from serialize data.

Comment: @C2486, would really appreciate if you could give out the solution in answers.

Comment: @Justinas, tried `FormData` but jquery is throwing an error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$().serialize()` will not include `$_FILES` content, so you need to use [`FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
$(document).on('click','#sub_prod',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata = new FormData($('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "product_add_back.php",
        method: "post",

        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        success: function(strMsg){}
    });
});
```

*Please note* that you pass 3 params: `data: formData`, `processData: false` and `contentType: false`

Comment: I can understand that `FormData` constructor is supplied with `form` and it creates and object as mentioned in the documentation but why do we use `[0]` along with it? I tried removing it and no data was submitted into the database(errors thrown). Would you please tell me why do we use `[0]`?

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe `$('form')` will return jQuery object that is not good for FormData parser. You need actual DOM element and it's located in `0` index of `$('form')`, so `$('form')[0]` gets you actual DOM element instead of jQuery wrapper

Comment: Which DOM element do we target using `$('form')[0]`?

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe The one that you select in query - `<form>`